# multiply a number and on top add another number

Tags: javascript, loops, math

I multiplied "1366*i+100" where i is any number but the 100 is added to the multiplication not on top. For example my best result was 1366*2+100 which is 2932 and not 2732 + 100 = 2832 (this is what I want how can I do it?). I tried in many ways and got different results, but the code I present here is just a quick overview and not my best result. So I know before anyone mention that the my math is wrong, though my words and logic is understandable(I think).

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){document.write(1366*i+100)};//this by far is a quick trial and error
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the 100 is added to the multiplication not on top"_?

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: @evolutionxbox what OP gets is `(1366+100)*i`, but he wants `(1366*i)+100`.

Comment: Research: BODMAS, BEDMAS, PEDMAS, BIDMAS, BOMDAS, etc --- also called the order of operations in mathematics.

Comment: On top I mean in addition to the result of the multiplication alone, so multiply 1*2 than the result is 2 then on top of 2+100.

Comment: Use brackets...

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, log to the console instead.

Comment: The snippet will output `10014662832419855646930829696621102812394 ` ... Please elaborate your question.

Comment: `1366*2+100` IS equal to `2832`, so this is all wrong.

Comment: it's the loop that adds altogether, and not alone (add 100)

Comment: "*So I know before anyone mention that the my math is wrong*". Yes, your math is wrong. See @evolutionxbox answers. PEMDAS, .., use brackets.

Comment: Yep, and if  you'd separate the values, you'd find them correct: `100, 1466, 2832, ...` What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Or if you want to total the amount, use reduce on an array of numbers.

Comment: @JobsonModesto I really like to know why you think there could be a result like 2932 for `1366*2+100`. Where have you seen that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just replace `document.write` with `console.log`, you will see that nothing is wrong with the code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(1366 * i + 100)
};
```

And if you really want the result from `i==2` to be `2932`, change it to this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log((1366 + 100) * i)
};
```

Comment: It's not that the code is wrong, but the OP's understanding.

Comment: I'm still without a perfect answer(it needs to be in document.write what can be done), if math (OP) wasn't the case I would not tag it in my question in advance.

Comment: @JobsonModesto You replace `console.log` with `document.write`. Arg0n did `console.log` to demonstrate the output that would land in a document.

Comment: Visit this page I am developing, go to link 5 or press the question mark triangle and type 5 (I just developed for computers so if you try using mobile it's not done yet). You scroll right until you reach the 1000 link, and notice the boxes are not placed evenly.

Comment: the parenthesis is the answer